# Is it possible to ping mongodb from pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

M using pymongo for connecting with a mLab-hosted mongodb.

I need to keep pinging the server occassionally to keep the connection alive.

I have not been able to find documentation for that.

Kindly suggest the pymongo equivalent of [ping](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/ping/) command.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [pymongo.database.Database.command](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html?highlight=command#pymongo.database.Database.command) to send custom command like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client.db_name.command('ping')
```

returns

```
{u'ok': 1.0}
```

Answer (score 8):

In order to perform the ping agnostic of any specific database, it is also possible to use the admin database in order to perform the ping. This was documented in the old [`mongo_client` documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.7.2/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.alive)

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client.admin.command('ping')
```